# Form does not work after clicking close button of bootstrap alert

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im facing a really strange problem here. I use bootstrap for some of my tooltips alerts etc. Now I have a ajax form that responds error messages in a alert if something is wrong. This all works fine but when i click the "close" button of the alert box the alert dissapears but then the form submit button does not work anymore? I dont know why it's behaviour is like this can someone help me out?

Also, when i do not close the alert, then when I enter new data and click on submit it does submit. Only after closing alert form does not submit anymore

Form (with error div)

```
<!-- ERROR BOX -->
<div id="regError" class="alert alert-error" style="margin-right: 20px; display: none;"></div>
<!-- ERROR BOX -->
<form id="registerform" action="ajax/register.php" method="post">
    <fieldset> <span class="help-block"><B>Jou gegevens</B></span>

        <input name="username" class="span4" type="text" value="Gebruikersnaam" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
        <input name="email" class="span4" type="text" value="Email adres" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" placeholder="Email adres">
        <input class="span4" type="text" value="Email adres (opnieuw)" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" placeholder="Email adres (opnieuw)">
        <input class="span4" type="text" value="Wachtwoord" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" placeholder="wachtwoord">
    </fieldset>
```

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
```

javascript ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#registerform").submit(function () {

        //Get al form data This = form and EL is element of the form
        var el = $(this),

            // get form action and method attribute
            url = el.attr('action'),
            type = el.attr('method'),

            // emty data array to fill with form data
            data = {}

            // The loop to get al form data
        el.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {

            var el = $(this)
            name = el.attr('name'),
                value = el.val();

            //make data object
            data[name] = value;

        });

        //Do the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#regError').html(response);
                $('#regError').fadeIn();
            }
        })

        return false;
    })
})
```

the PHP is just to test if it works..

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>';
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: not seeing a submit button here...

Comment: added submit also end form tag is also there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well because i could not find a solution i just removed the close button.